# How to detect the syntax of code whether it's CSS or JS using jQuery or PHP?

Tags: php, jquery, css

I'm writing a simple PHP code for minifying CSS and JS files. And in the code I want it to be able to detect whether the source code is CSS or JS. Can anyone show me an example?

Comment: What have you tried? Seems very simple to me. Css and JavaScript have different styles. Shouldn't be to hard to see the difference

Comment: They also have different file extensions. Use a library instead of creating your own

Comment: You got a tool online https://jscompress.com/ or use PHP tutorial http://www.aaron-fisher.com/articles/web/php/minifying-css-and-javascript-on-the-fly/

Comment: Ha! Didn't even think about that. @charlietfl

Comment: Hi @Andreas. I'm trying to create a js/css compressor which is like what people do online, but I want it to be more user intuitive. Other sites put different inputs for css and js. Mine is I want to put only one textarea for both css and js, then the code with automatically detect whether its css or js and minify the inputed code.

Comment: So it's not a "file" as you stated in question? Either way a regex such as the answer below will probably do just fine

Comment: @Andreas Actually I want to put an option for the user to choose if he/she wants to input or upload files/multiple files. Thanks so much for your comments :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `Regular expression` and [`preg_match`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) function  like this :

for detecting a javascript variable `(var+\s)[_a-zA-Z][_a-zA-Z0-9]{0,30}`

```
<?php
preg_match('/(var+\s)[_a-zA-Z][_a-zA-Z0-9]{0,30}/', 'var test', $matches, 
PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
print_r($matches);
?>
```

and for css try this `([^\r\n,{}]+)(,(?=[^}]*{)|\s*{)`

```
<?php
preg_match('/([^\r\n,{}]+)(,(?=[^}]*{)|\s*{)/', '.clearfix:before,.clearfix:after{display:table;}', $matches, 
PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
print_r($matches);
?>
```

for more [regex see](https://regexr.com/)

Comment: Thanks for this simple code. It works :)